# HttpServletResponse encoding issue

Tags: java

I have an API that returns JSON, it actually returns it using the default encoding (I believe it's UTF-8), but japanese and arabic characters are displayed as ??? or some junk

My question is: is there an easy way to display japanese characters ? I tried by setting page encoding to UTF-8 but it doesn't work.Can any body suggest solution?

Comment: The problem lies in the word "believe".  Check your assumptions.  Either the JSON isn't encoded or the display isn't interpreting them properly.  Just two spots to check.  Either or both could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no error somewhere, it should work with UTF-8. See:

- [test](http://winrus.com/utf8-jap.htm)
- [article](http://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/encodings.html)

Here is [Hiragana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana) japanese letters [UTF-8 encoding page](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=12352).

<strike>So, I think you made a mistake or your API isn't doing its job.</strike>

EDIT:

as duffymo pointed out in comment to your question:

> Either the JSON isn't encoded or the display isn't interpreting them properly. Just two spots to check. Either or both could be wrong